# Training Stanford POS tagger for unstructured sentences

Tags: python, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

For the sentences like 'x represents apples' or 'x and y represents apples and bananas' I want POS tagger to appropriately tag the words as if for the sentence 'Java Represents Coffee beans'. Or is there any other better parser which can give POS tagging for these unstructured sentences.

I also need to find dependencies in the sentence for which I am trying with Stanford parser, if anyone is aware of better ways please suggest.
I am trying all these stuffs in python.

Answer (score 0):

I use SpaCy. https://spacy.io/

It is designed as an out-of-the-box NLP pipeline, so you shouldn't need to change anything about the model. It gives the "universal" and "Penn treebank" POS tags for the given sentence.

It also does dependency tagging.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
>>> import nltk
>>> import re
>>> from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
>>> from nltk.tag import pos_tag
>>> sentence = 'x and y represents apples and bananas'
>>> sentence1 = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
>>> sentence1 = nltk.pos_tag(sentence1)
>>> grammar = "NP: {<DT>?<JJ>*<NN>}"
>>> cp = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar)
>>> result = cp.parse(sentence1)
>>> print(result)
(S
  (NP x/NN)
  and/CC
  y/JJ
  represents/VBZ
  apples/NNS
  and/CC
  bananas/NNS)
>>> result.draw()
```

[image: Dependency tree]

Or

You can see more details for [a sentence POS and dependency tree.](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html)

Comment: This statement should be parsed like "Ram and Sita likes mangos and apples respectively". But here x and y are not categorized as nouns, so that is the challenge in this task.